# Volley NetworkImageView not showing for some urls, content type maybe wrong

Tags: android, android-volley, content-type, imageurl, networkimageview

My app uses the NetworkIamgeView class in the Volley library to show the images. For some urls the images are not shown correctly. I noticed that these links point to png files, however the content type is image/jpeg. Is that the cause of the problem?

http://baseurl/Standard1280x720.jpg/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.744.415.png

However these links are all rendered correctly on the browser app on Android phones. Are there some simple fixes to handle this?

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Volley does not support redirection.Had to modify the library to handle http 301 results.

Comment: check https://github.com/apptik/jus it is based on volley and supports redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: No, Volley does not use the content type when [parsing](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java#170) the image. It delegates the task to the [BitmapFactory](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp). This means that it could work differently on different devices and also that supported formats can vary.

Q2:

> Are there some simple fixes to handle this?

By

> For some urls the images are not shown correctly

It is not clear what the issue is. I suggest enabling logs to see what exactly is received form the server. You can also just extend [ImageRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java), add it to the queue and log the bytes there.